# Leaving the plug attached to the socket

Tags: usb, short-circuit, energy, plug, socket

It would be really helpful for me to leave the USB plug (the "brick") plugged into the power socket.

I would not connect the cable, which could potentially short if it touched a conductor, but only the brick itself, so I would plug the cable in each time I need to charge my phone:

[image: Something like this]

- Does this consume energy?
- Is this any dangerous (as it is said about leaving the cable plugged
  in)?

Thanks in advance,
SP

*P.S. I do not really know which site to ask on, so sorry in case I am in the wrong place.*

Comment: How would the cable even be able to short by touching a conductor? The output is isolated, and should have enough isolation, unless you bought cheaply made unsafe chargers. Yes, it consumes electricity. Yes, leaving any electrical device plugged in unattended is always a risk of danger. Yes, this is a product usage question and should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this consume energy? Yes. Although not enough to make a difference in your electric bill.

Is this any dangerous? We tend not to leave electronics plugged in if not in use just in case.

Perhaps a better solution would be to use a power strip. Turn it on when phone is charging, then turn off when not charging phone. You can leave the cable connected and out of the way so no one trips on it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How much energy does it consume? Does it consume as much as when I plug my smartphone in?

Comment: There is a rating of amps on it. That much (not quite the max. though) it could supply when charging your phone. When not charging somewhere in the very very low number of the rating. The only way to know would be to measure it because they don't usually show that number.

Comment: Thanks again. You've been very clear!